# AWS API Gateway - edit Integration Response in SAM template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

To edit the Integration Response I needed to uncheck "Use Lambda Proxy integration".
1 - why only the `Integration Response` was disabled when the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" was checked, and not also "Method Request", "Integration Request" and "Method Response"? Aren't they part of the "Lambda Proxy integration"?

2 - I have a SAM template, how can I use it to uncheck the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" and edit the Integration Response? I want to have default response headers for all requests.

This is my SAM template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  EZDrive

  Sample SAM Template for EZDrive

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'content-type'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      # AllowCredentials: true  Uncomment only if you choose a specific origin instead of the * wildcard.
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128
    Runtime: python3.8
    Architectures:
      - x86_64

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ez_server/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post
  LoginFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ez_server/
      Handler: auth.login
      Events:
        Login:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /login
            Method: post
      Role: !GetAtt LoginFunctionRole.Arn

  ImportTransactionsFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ez_server/
      Handler: app.import_transactions
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        Schedule:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Name: ImportTransactionsSchedule
            Schedule: cron(0 0/12 * * ? *)

  LoginFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-LoginFunctionRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoPowerUser

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```